# Swrve in app messages

Tags: android, message, messaging

I have swrve SDK implemented in my app. Push notifications, events, everything. And all that works fine except in-app-messages (https://docs.swrve.com/user-documentation/in-app-messaging/intro-to-in-app-messages/).

Did anyone had any experience with Swrve in app messages? The documentation doesn`t say anything about this, only about console configuration which is fine since I recieve the message when I need to do and the buttons respond to user input.

When I click on any button that does some action in the app, the app restarts... Swrve simply restarts my activity. Does anybody have a clue why ?

Cheers

Comment: I have found out that Swrve SDK has in it`s source code for Android (SwrveIntentHelper -> openDeepLink) it recieves an intent and then in uses it to startActivity.... This is why my activity is restarted. But still, why does this work like this ? It should not restart it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all I have created another activity where I added the intent filter for receiving this kind of intents (deep link). When you receive deep link in game, it simply opens that new activity on the top of the MAinActivity and you get the URL from Swrve like this onCreate SwrveActivity:

```
if (getIntent().getAction() == Intent.ACTION_VIEW) {
        Uri data = getIntent().getData();
        MainActivity.processDeepLink(data.toString());
}
```

After that you must call finish() onResume of that activity so it should close that temporary activity so your app could continue normally.

Comment: Nice... thanks for the info! If you have it, can you please share the intent-filter configuration in your manifest?

Comment: @anitteb Sorry, I cannot remember which project was this, it was a long time ago.